# What tool should I use to cut off the GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, hardware, pi-zero-w

I would like the make the Pi Zero W smaller and cut off the part of the PCB that holds the GPIO pins.  What tool should I use to do so?  Is a Dremel/rotary tool too destructive?

I'm thinking an XActo blade might be more precise, and then I can score it and break it down the line I scored.

Comment: You will probably kill the Pi by cutting traces that should not be cut.

Comment: The way I figure it, if the Pi is OK with the GPIO pins not connected, it should be fine if they are also cut off and not connected.

Comment: The question is, will it be fine without the tracks that might be embedded in the part of the board you've cut off. I believe the board is at least 4 layers so who knows what traces are inside the board that you can't see.

Comment: @RogerJones That is a very good ancillary question.  Once I try chopping it up, I will know for certain.  I will try the Xacto method first and see where that gets me.

Comment: OK. The circuit board is made of essentially [fiberglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FR-4) so I think that careful use of a rotary cutting disc will give you the best results, be sure to wear a face mask as the dust is not nice :)

Comment: OK, I cut it off with an Xacto knife and it looks OK.  I'll fire it up and see what happens.

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I didn't test it beforehand, so it might have been a dud.  I will be trying it again in a few

Comment: OK, so that's 2 dead Pis.  The second time around, I tried to go a little farther out, but then a miss with the blade cut part of the board I didn't intend to.  In both cases, the power LED does not turn on, and I get no video over HDMI.  The USB hub powers up, but that's probably because the power leads are connected.  Maybe if I want to do some science later I will start by cutting the outer most GPIOs off to see if my hypothesis works at all.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to make the Pi Zero smaller?

Comment: I applaud your commitment to the scientific method for establishing facts. And I'd suggest that you obtain a copy and then modify the Gerber files for the RPi Zero, BUT it seems that [the Foundation considers the RPi hardware proprietary](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132891); i.e. the Gerbers aren't available, at least not from open sources.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser You may be able to repair the first one. I hope you didn't cut some lines just under the gpio holes (red line in my image). Check if the ground on the one side of the board is short circuited with the ground of the other side of the board. If the 2 grounds does not connect just bridge them with a wire.
Image: https://prnt.sc/mcno6r

Comment: I'm trying to make it fit into a case.  As it turns out, I was able to modify the case to get it to fit, but the Pi Zero would fit better with the GPIO pins removed.  Since this is going to be a computer project and not an IoT project, I won't miss the pins.  I tried to cut on the outside of the white line, but may have killed the ground that @GramThanos mentioned, so I'll try to resuscitate them and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you will kill your Pi Zero. Good luck missing important tracks as seen in these X-Rays:

[image]

[image]

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=163317

Comment: On first look, I don't see "important tracks" on the headers part, except from 2 tracks just under the 2nd row of headers. But we can't be sure :P

Comment: That's a 1.3 and I'm asking about a 0 W.....

Comment: I realise that - it was the only x ray images that I could find. So did it work or did you kill it ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you kill more boards, consider that the mechanical stress applied during the cutting may be enough to kill a PCB, even if you don't cut through any traces. I have successfully cut populated PCBs, and the trick is to make a scratch-like cut on each side with an Xacto knife, then gradually deepen the cuts until they meet, without trying to bend the PCB.

To find out if you can cut without destroying any traces, you'll have to check every [via](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_(electronics)) on the part you're cutting off. If a via is not connected to any GPIO pad, it's an unrelated signal you likely want to keep. Even then, there's no guarantee that you don't cut any "buried" traces this way. You need to see a complete PCB layout to be sure.